# magento add two multiselect fields to admin configuration

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Ive been working on a module and I need to add two multiselect fields to admin with different options. In system.xml i have under fields tag:

```
                    <item_att translate="label">
                        <label>Item: </label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <source_model>mymodule/system_config_source_item</source_model>
                    </item_att>
                    <product_att translate="label">
                        <label>Product: </label>
                        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        <source_model>mymodule/system_config_source_product</source_model>
                    </product_att>
```

My sources item.php and product.php passes basic arrays with the desired options.
When I try to add them separately, both multiselect fields work but when I try to add them both configuration pages shows up blank without any errors. What can be the problem?